# How to enable logging debug messages when root logger is INFO?

Tags: log4j, apache-commons-logging

I use logger `org.apache.commons.logging.Log`.

File log4j.properties is:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, S

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.logger.org.springsource.sawt=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.w3c.tidy=INFO
...................
```

When I use debug method of `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` it doesn't log anything.

How to change log4j.properties to enable logger log debug messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple.

If you want to log all debug,info,warn.error,fatal messages from logger you need to take name of logger provided at instantiation by method `LogFactory.getLog(loggerName)` and append it to log4j.logger`. Thus you get

```
log4j.logger.loggerName=DEBUG
```

But it's common that `loggerName` is String from `getClass()` method. Thus you can use package name to set logger's level for that package.